# Set multiple EventListener to element but delete single ones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have an element, here in the example - $(window). I would like to put several of the same EventListeners on this element, here "scroll" twice. These two EventListeners each perform different functions, which I cannot / do not want to connect with each other, shown here in a simplified manner. How can I delete individual EventListeners?

Here is the little example I made.

```js
// Logs 1 when scrolling
$(window).on("scroll", () => {
    console.log(1);
});

// Logs 2 when scrolling
$(window).bind("scroll", () => {
    console.log(2);
});

// After 2 seconds stop logging 1
setTimeout(() => {
  $(window).unbind("scroll"); // remove only logging 1
}, 2000);
```

```css
#test {
  height:10000px;
  width:100vw;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Note bind/unbind are deprecated and use on/off internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `.namespace` to your event.  This will still fire the same `scroll` event, but allows you to reference it with `.off` (or `.unbind` in your original code).

Here's your code updated:

```js
// Logs 1 when scrolling
$(window).on("scroll.temp", () => {
  console.log(1);
});

// Logs 2 when scrolling
$(window).on("scroll", () => {
  console.log(2);
});

// After 2 seconds stop logging 1
setTimeout(() => {
  $(window).off("scroll.temp"); // remove only logging 1
}, 2000);
```

```css
#test {
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

More info from: https://api.jquery.com/on/

> **Event names and namespaces**
>
> Any event names can be used for the events argument. jQuery will pass through the browser's standard JavaScript event types, calling the handler function when the browser generates events due to user actions such as click.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`event.namespace`](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for this and add multiple namespaces for scroll event like:

```
$(window).on("scroll.event1", () => {
    console.log(1);
});

$(window).on("scroll.event2", () => {
    console.log(2);
});
```

and when you want to remove event 1, you can simply call [`.off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) on it like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  $(window).off("scroll.event1"); // remove only logging 1
}, 2000);
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(window).on("scroll.event1", () => {
  console.log(1);
});

$(window).on("scroll.event2", () => {
  console.log(2);
});

// After 2 seconds stop logging 1
setTimeout(() => {
  $(window).off("scroll.event1"); // remove only logging 1
}, 2000);
```

```css
#test {
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```